# How to add or see Acumatica Objects in a new project using visual studio c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, acumatica

I need to create a custom data provider that outside Acumatica ERP; I will create the  using Visual Studio. I need to be able to access and use Acumatica objects like Data Providers in my Visual Studio and do not know the proper way to add them - please let me know how.

My PC already has Acumatica Framework installed; I need to know the next step in order to be able to see the objects in Visual Studio

Note: I already know how to use the SOAP and WebAPI of Acumatica and am not going to use that for this project.

Comment: you should clarify if you are creating an embedded customization within Acumatica or an integration using web services? Both of which are covered in the training which gives you the examples and question you need to get going on either.

Comment: Thanks, Brendan. I will be doing an embedded customization. Can you suggest a raining link. Will be creating it in an Acumatica 5.30 instance

Comment: The Acumatica T100 class is what you should start with: https://openuni.acumatica.com/courses/development/t100-introduction-to-acumatica-framework/